FireBase Push Notifications (FCM) in Unity
Try to integrating FCM in unity for push notifications and subscribe the functions OnTokenReceived & OnMessageReceived but push notifications not working in device when I schedule them from firebase console
private void InitPushNotifications() {
    Debug.LogError("Push Notifications Subscribed");
    Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenRegistrationOnInitEnabled = true;
    
    Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenReceived;
    Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
    
}

public void OnTokenReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.TokenReceivedEventArgs token) 
{
    Debug.LogError("Received Registration Token: " + token.Token);
    UserPushNotification.SetValue(token.Token);
}

public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.MessageReceivedEventArgs e) 
{
    Debug.LogError("Received a new message from: " + e.Message.From);

    var notification = e.Message.Notification;
    
    if (notification != null) {
        Debug.LogError("title: " + notification.Title);
        Debug.LogError("body: " + notification.Body);
        var android = notification.Android;
        if (android != null) {
            Debug.LogError("android channel_id: " + android.ChannelId);
        }
    }
    
    if (e.Message.From.Length > 0)
        Debug.LogError("from: " + e.Message.From);
    
    if (e.Message.Link != null) {
        Debug.LogError("link: " + e.Message.Link.ToString());
    }
    
    if (e.Message.Data.Count > 0) {
        Debug.LogError("data:");
        foreach (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> iter in
                 e.Message.Data) {
            Debug.LogError("  " + iter.Key + ": " + iter.Value);
        }
    }
    
}

I followed all the steps mentioned in the Firebase documentation for push notifications. For Android, I also added the JobIntentService in the AndroidManifest.xml file as specified:
<service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.MessageForwardingService"      android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"      android:exported="false" > </service>

Before this FCM update, my push notifications were working but now they are not. Also there is no custom entry point in my application so configuring an android entry point activity is not required in my case.
AndroidManifest.xml  file are attached for better understanding.

Try debugging delivery using the Aggregate Delivery Data API:https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#aggregated_delivery_data_via_the_data_api
"Also there is no custom entry point in my application so configuring an android entry point activity is not required in my case." To be clear do you mean you are letting the SDK create one itself instead of you doing it manually?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client#configuring_an_android_entry_point_activity
